# Angular + web sockets, how to use promises?

Tags: angularjs, sockets, factory, angular-promise, autobahn

I using Autobahn.js for web socket connection (i need to subscribe to socket event).

I use $timeout for check socket event. But i think, it's wrong, incorrect not optimal, i don't want to use $timeout in controller, maybe promises helps me?
How i can catch socket message in controller without $timeout?

```js
app.factory('socket',['$rootScope',
function($rootScope) {
    var pubsub = new ab.Session(
      'wss://site.com/',
      function(session) {
        return session;
      },
      function(code, reason) {
      }
    );
    return {
      pubsub: pubsub
    };

  }]);




app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$timeout', 'socket', function($timeout, socket) {

 $timeout(function() {
  
  $scope.data = socket.pubsub.subscribe('3434424234324', function(topic, data) { 
    
    
    // do something if data. 
    // data contains socket message.

  });
}, 300);
  
}]);

//3434424234324 - subscriber id
```

Comment: I find the example on https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket is quite helpful to my project, the factory is returning a reference to a data stream while inside the controller you can assign it to one of your $scope variable. With autobahn you can do similar stuff here. See that whenever the data steam is changed, angular would detect it so that you don't have to manually add $timeout func to wrap it.

Comment: Thank you, but how look like implementation with my code? Can you write ? :)

Answer (score 3):

One of the fundamental ideas of WebSockets is that they are asynchronous. You don't have to keep track of when they will do things! If end up using `$timeout` to check whether a socket has received a message, then something has probably gone very wrong! That can to `$timeout` can be removed completely.

All socket interfaces will expose handler callback functions which will be responsible for dealing with the different events that a socket can trigger. What you need to do is find the `message` event handler for Autobahn and manually trigger a `$scope` digest there.

Autobahn uses a publisher/subscriber model, which means that you'll need to get hold of the `subscribe` event handler:

```
socket.pubsub.subscribe('3434424234324', function(topic, data) { 
  // do something if data. 
  // data contains socket message.

  // let angular know something async has happened
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

However, rather than trying to change all your code in order to act like this, I would recommend wrapping Autobahn up into an Angular factory which handles this kind of behaviour for you. Better still, use a library like [angular-wamp](https://github.com/voryx/angular-wamp) that already does this.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but i'm Angular beginner, i can't make that you say :) i need simple solution.

Comment: OK, delete `$timeout` and add `$scope.$apply();` to your subscribe callback.

Comment: socket.pubsub.subscribe('556654665', function(topic, data) { 

  $scope.$apply();
});    error of autobahn :(

Comment: @desp I'm afraid I can't guess what that error is. If you want help with something you'll have to update your question to explain what the problem is.

Comment: Look at the [Autobahn docs](http://autobahn.ws/js/). The socket lets you know when it is connected and ready for sending data with the `connection.onopen` callback. If you use angular-wamp, it handles it in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with something quick as following:

```
app.factory('socket',['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    var connection = new autobahn.Connection({
        url: 'url',
        realm: 'realm'
    });

    var collection = {
       'topic1': [],
       'topic2': []
    };

    connection.onopen = function(session) {
        session.subscribe('topic1').then(function(res){
            collection.topic1.push(res);
        });
    };

    connection.open();

    return {
       collection: collection
    }
}]);
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['socket', function(socket) {
     $scope.socket = socket;
}]);
```

Then in your mainCtrl, you have access to your topics data, as they're stored inside collection. If you want to display it in the template, you can simply use something like {{ socket.collection.topic1 }}, or ng-repeat or whatever.

Comment: Thank you so much! But i don't understood, when i should put subscriber's id, please see http://i.imgur.com/WRkcdeu.png

Comment: The subscriber id in your context is the 'topic' in my example

Comment: Thank you. But i have an error "WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.com:34015/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received". What the version of Autobahn i should use?